# Looking to introduce browser push/bidirectional communications to my JSF application

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, websocket, tomcat6, long-polling

I am looking into methods to introduce push technology to my JSF web application.
I am currently serving this need using JavaScript polling and this is too costly for a serious web application.

I've read about some possible options but I don't want to limit my answers to these since I am not sure how good they are so I will not name them.

I am running on top of Tomcat 6, JSF 2.0 and using jQuery on the client Side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PrimeFaces `<p:push>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf) uses websockets. This only requires Jetty running next to Tomcat on a different port, because Jetty supports websockets natively (Tomcat 6 doesn't, only Tomcat 8 or newer does). See chapter 6 of [User's Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html) for detailed explanation. Another alternative is [ICEfaces Ajax Push](http://www.icesoft.org/projects/ICEfaces/ajax-push.jsf).